# LINQ Lambda Group By with Sum

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I can do this in method syntax but I'm trying to improve my lambda skills how can I do:

```
SELECT SUM([job_group_quota]) as 'SUM'
FROM [dbo].[tbl_job_session]
WHERE [job_group_job_number] = @jobnum
and [job_group_ID] like @sess
GROUP BY [job_group_job_number]
```

I've been messing around with it but can't get it right.

```
lnq.tbl_job_sessions.GroupBy(a => a.job_group_job_number == jnum)
                    .Select(b => new { b.job_group_quota}).Sum();
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

A general example:

```
query
.GroupBy(item => item.GroupKey)
.Select(group => group.Sum(item => item.Aggregate));
```

Answer (score 2):

Few Group by Examples

public void GroupBy1()
        {
            var personList = dbEntities.People.GroupBy(m => m.PersonType).Select(m => new { PersonType = m.Key, Count = m.Count() });
        }

```
    public void GroupBy2()
    {
        var personList = dbEntities.People.GroupBy(m => new { m.PersonType, m.FirstName }).Select(m => new { PersonType = m.Key, Count = m.Count() });
    }

    public void GroupBy3()
    {
        var personList = dbEntities.People.Where(m => m.EmailPromotion != 0).GroupBy(m => new { m.PersonType, m.FirstName }).Select(m => new { PersonType = m.Key, Count = m.Count() });
    }

    public void GroupBy4()
    {
        var personList = dbEntities.People.GroupBy(m => new { m.PersonType, m.FirstName }).Where(m => m.Count() > 70).Select(m => new { PersonType = m.Key, Count = m.Count() });
    }

    public void GroupBy5()
    {
        var personList = dbEntities.People
            .GroupBy(m =>
                new
                {
                    m.PersonType
                }).Where(m => m.Count() > 70)
                    .Select(m =>
                        new
                        {
                            PersonType = m.Key,
                            Count = m.Count()
                        });

        var list1 = dbEntities.People.
            GroupBy(m => new { m.PersonType }).
            Select(m =>
                new
                {
                    Type = m.Key,
                    Count = m.Count()
                })
            .Where(
                   m => m.Count > 70
                && m.Type.PersonType.Equals("EM")
                || m.Type.PersonType.Equals("GC"));
    }

    public void GroupBy6()
    {
        var list1 = dbEntities.People.
            GroupBy(m => new { m.PersonType, m.EmailPromotion }).Select(m =>
                new
                {
                    Type = m.Key,
                    Count = m.Count()
                })
            .Where
            (
                m => m.Count > 70 && m.Type.EmailPromotion.Equals(0) &&
                (
                    m.Type.PersonType.Equals("EM") ||
                    m.Type.PersonType.Equals("GC")
                ));
    }

    public void GroupBy7()
    {
        var list1 = dbEntities.People.
            GroupBy(m => m.PersonType).
            Select(c =>
                new
                {
                    Type = c.Key,
                    Total = c.Sum(p => p.BusinessEntityID)
                });
    }

    public void GroupBy8()
    {
        var list1 = dbEntities.People.
            GroupBy(m => m.PersonType).
            Select(c =>
                new
                {
                    Type = c.Key,
                    Count = c.Count(),
                    Total = c.Sum(p => p.BusinessEntityID)
                });
    }

    public void GroupBy9()
    {
        var list1 = dbEntities.People.
            GroupBy(m => m.PersonType).
            Select(c =>
                new
                {
                    Type = c.Key,
                    Max = c.Max(),
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a key-to-sum Dictionary result.

```
var allJobQuota = jobSessions.GroupBy(s => s.jobNumber)
                             .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum(s => s.quota));
```

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to iterate the grouped values getting the key and totals, and how to get totals directly (like previous). Both using only lambda operator.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> data = GetPopulatedData();

        var totals = data.GroupBy(x =>
            new { x.Name, x.City, x.ZipCode }).Select(y =>
                y.Sum(i => i.SomeValue));

        var groupsForIterate = data.GroupBy(x =>
            new { x.Name, x.City, x.ZipCode });

        Console.WriteLine("Totals: ");
        foreach (var total in totals)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(total);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Categories: ");
        foreach (var categ in groupsForIterate)
        {
            // You can refer to one field like this: categ.Key.Ciduad
            Console.WriteLine("Group" + categ.Key);
            Console.WriteLine(categ.Sum(x => x.SomeValue));
        }

        //Output:
        //Totals:
        //1
        //2
        //1
        //Categories:
        //Group{ Name = Mark, City = BCN, ZipCode = 00000 }
        //1
        //Group{ Name = Mark, City = BCN, ZipCode = 000000 }
        //2
        //Group{ Name = John, City = NYC, ZipCode = 000000 }
        //1
    }

    private static List<Person> GetPopulatedData()
    {
        List<Person> datos = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person(){Name="Mark", City = "BCN",
                ZipCode = "00000", SomeValue = 1}, // group A

            new Person(){Name="Mark", City = "BCN",
                ZipCode = "000000", SomeValue = 1}, // group B

            new Person(){Name="Mark", City = "BCN",
                ZipCode = "000000", SomeValue = 1}, // group B

            new Person(){Name="John", City = "NYC",
                ZipCode = "000000", SomeValue = 1}, // group C
        };
        return datos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sum Ficha_Venda and Entrada from Movimento:

var query = from bd in db.Movimento
                            where (movimento.Data != null ? bd.Data == movimento.Data : bd.Data == movimento.Data)
                            && (bd.Loja == Loja)
                            group bd by bd.Data into t
                            select new {entrada = t.Sum(bd=> bd.Entrada), ficha = t.Sum(bd=> bd.Ficha_Venda)};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lnq.tbl_job_sessions.Where(x => x.job_group_job_number == @jobnum 
                          && x.job_group_ID.Contains(""+ @sess +"")
                        )
                 .GroupBy(a => a.job_group_job_number)
                 .Select(b => new 
                              { 
                                SUM = b.Sum( p => p.job_group_quota)
                              }
                        );
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?