# LINQ Query or query to table in C# with grouping and totalling

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ Lambda Group By with Sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970070/linq-lambda-group-by-with-sum)

LINQ Query or query to table in C# required.

i have a dynamically created DATA Table :

```
            COLUMN:  City    Deposittype  DepositAmount                  
            ROWS :  city1     new          100
                    city1     new          200
                    city2     old          200
                    city2     old          100
                    city2     new          200
                     city3    new          100
```

Want to Group by city, calc sum of depositamount for specified Deposittype.

Example, for condition depositType= new

i want a row like

```
           city1 city2 city3
            300   200   100
```

I want sum of DepositAmounts Grouped by City with specific Deposit type. i.e Result row should have city1 city2 city3 as column names, under which sum of 'Depositamounts' for a specified loan type say Deposittype = new.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = table.Where(x=>x.Deposit=="new")
                  .GroupBy(x=> x.City)
                  .Select(x=>new { City=x.Key,Sum=x.Sum(y=>y.Amount) } )
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: where clause cannot be used for table

Comment: @ThejoArjun it depends what type `table` is of. I assumed it to be  `List<YourObject>`

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Table
    {
        public string City { get; set; }

        public string Deposit { get; set; }

        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    }

             var list = new List<Table>
                           {
                               new Table { City = "city1", Deposit = "new", Amount = 100 },
                               new Table { City = "city1", Deposit = "new", Amount = 200 },
                               new Table { City = "city2", Deposit = "old", Amount = 200 },
                               new Table { City = "city2", Deposit = "old", Amount = 100 },
                               new Table { City = "city2", Deposit = "new", Amount = 200 },
                               new Table { City = "city3", Deposit = "new", Amount = 100 }
                           };
            //You can get all items by grouping with city and deposit in here.
            var result = (from c in list
                          group c by new {c.City,c.Deposit} into d
                          select new
                          {
                              City = d.Key.City,
                              Deposit = d.Key.Deposit,
                              SumAmount = d.Sum(x => x.Amount)
                          });

            //If you want only new,
            var resultNew = result.Where(x => x.Deposit == "new");
            //If you want only old,
            var resultOld = result.Where(x => x.Deposit == "old");
```

Comment: If one of the answers helped you, please consider marking it as the answer. The same would apply to your other questions, by the way. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work