# Don't bind duplicate items to checked list box

Tags: c#, linq, checkboxlist

I've got a list of objects which have team details of salesmen.
the list has several teams which have the same name but the salesman is different.

the teamDetails class has the following attributes:

```
string teamName;
string region;
int teamSales;
string salesmanFullName;
string salesmanAddress;
```

the user has an option to find all the teams which have sales over a certain value. these teams are then added to a check box list.

this is how i'm populating the check box list:

```
var viewList = from toSearch in GlobalVariables.allSalesmenList
               where toSearch.teamSales > Convert.ToInt32(txtSalesSearch.Text)
               select toSearch;
SearchCheckedListBox.DataSource = viewList.ToList();
SearchCheckedListBox.DisplayMember = "teamName";
```

the problem I'm having is the team name is shown more than once if the team has more than one salesman.

how would I prevent the checkbox from having repeated values?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to do here?

Comment: the checkbox has repeated values, I dont want this. For example if "team 1" has 5 members, the checkboxlist will have 5 "team 1"'s displayed.

Comment: Did you use viewList.ToList.Distinct();

Comment: @saravanan Won't work, as they're different. Also you forgot to call ToList!

Comment: Try adding `group toSearch by toSearch.teamName into toSearchGrouped` before the select and then in the select put `select toSearchGrouped.Key`. Should work.

Comment: @Pindo: You should be using an aggregate sum(teamSales) and then group by team name so that you will get the exact desired results.

Comment: @Pindo: you can try out something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970070/linq-lambda-group-by-with-sum

Answer (score 1):

Try to use distinct with comparer:

```
var viewList = from toSearch in GlobalVariables.allSalesmenList
           where toSearch.teamSales > Convert.ToInt32(txtSalesSearch.Text)
           select toSearch;


SearchCheckedListBox.DataSource = viewList.Distinct(new TeamComparer()).ToList();
SearchCheckedListBox.DisplayMember = "teamName";
```

Comparer code:

```
    public class TeamComparer : IEqualityComparer<teamDetails>
    {
        public bool Equals(teamDetails x, teamDetails y)
        {
            if (x.teamName == y.teamName) return true;

            return false;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(teamDetails obj)
        {
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null)) return 0;

            return obj.teamName.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this

```
SearchCheckedListBox.DataSource = viewList.GroupBy(x => x.teamName)
                                          .Select(g => g.First())
                                          .ToList();
```

If you are planing to use the same trick more than once, you can write an extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, S>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, S> selector)
{
    return list.GroupBy(selector).Select(g => g.First());
}
```

then the code would be

```
SearchCheckedListBox.DataSource = viewList.DistinctBy(x => x.teamName).ToList();
```